# Format Column Width with Printf

Tags: bash, awk, printf, paste

I am attempting to merge three files using 'paste' and 'awk'. However, the columns are not adjusting to the longest string of characters. All files are formatted in the same manner as below.

- F gge0001x
- D 12-30-2006
- T 14:15:20
- S a69
- B 15.8
- M gge06001
- P 30.1

Below is my faulty code.

```
$ paste <(awk '{print $1}' lineid) <
(awk '{printf("%-13.10s\n", $1)}' gge0001x) <
(awk '{printf("%-13.10s\n", $1)}' gge0001y) <
(awk '{printf("%-13.10s\n", $1)}' gge0001z)
```

This code results in misaligned columns as pictured below.
[image: Misaligned Columns]

---

Input File 1

```
F 
D 
T 
S 
B 
M 
P  
Q  
R  
U  
X 
A    
G    
H  
O  
C  
K  
W  
L
```

Input File 2

```
gge0006x
12-30-2006
14:05:23
a69
15.4
gge06001
30.8 
19.2 
1006.2 
1012.7 
36.2
38.994   
107.71   
8.411 
37.084 
7.537 
28.198 
212.52 
68.1
```

Input File 3

```
gge0006y
12-30-2006 
14:05:55
a69
15.3
gge06001
30.6 
21.1 
1006.6 
1014.6 
36.1
38.994   
107.71   
8.433 
36.705 
7.621 
27.623 
210.51 
68
```

Input File 4

```
gge0006z
12-30-2006
14:06:28
a69
15.7
gge06001
30.3 
23.5 
1008 
1014.1 
36.6
38.994   
107.71   
8.434 
36.508 
7.546 
27.574 
208.08 
67.6
```

---

Results for `paste file1 file2 file3 file4 | column -t`
[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the input files you are using? This will greatly aid testing.

Comment: Sorry, I will do so right now.

Comment: If you're just trying to format the output nicely have you considered using the `column` command instead of messing with the fields individually using `awk`? e.g. `paste file1 file2 file3 file4 | column -t`

Comment: Thank you, steeldriver. No luck either with that code. I edited my post with a screenshot using the suggested code.

Comment: Next time, please don't use screenshots to show text. Just paste it directly into your question, same as you did with your code. That way, we can easily copy it and compare to what we get, the page is slightly less heavy to load and text-to-speech software can read it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input files have DOS `\r\n` line endings. Remove the carriage returns with the `dos2unix` command or with `sed -i 's/\r$//'`

Comment: THANK YOU! I haven't slept all night. I would have never figured this out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The command `paste` separate entries with tabs, which are then interpreted as a variable number of spaces upon display. If your input is already padded with whitespace, you may try deleting tabs from the output of `paste`, with `| tr -d '\t'`, or turning each tab into a single space,with`| tr '\t' ' '` (on my system, the first can be achieved using `paste -d ''`, but I don't know whether this is portable, and the second can be achieved with `paste -d ' '`; telling `paste` to use spaces as delimiters).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm having no luck with either code you suggested.